# get jquery :contains values into an array

Tags: jquery, contains

I've got a table and want to get an array of cell values which contain a query provided by the user.

For example, the user inputs '20', and the table is

```
120
240
220
110
```

I want an array to contain

```
[120, 220]
```

I currently have

```
var data_list = jQuery('td:contains('+seach_val+')','table#data');
```

and I've also tried the above with .text() to see if that would get me the text, but none of this seems to work.

Should be pretty simple I thought, but I'm having some trouble with this.

Comment: It should work. http://jsfiddle.net/Mj5G4/

Comment: This may be obvious, but are you sure you are not misspelling `seach_val` when you may mean `search_val`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to create an array, the following code works:

```
<table id="data">
    <tr><td>120</td></tr>
    <tr><td>240</td></tr>
    <tr><td>350</td></tr>
    <tr><td>220</td></tr>
</table>

search_val = 20;
data_list = [];
jQuery('td:contains('+search_val+')','table#data').each(function(){
    data_list.push($(this).text());
});
console.log(data_list);
```

This outputs in the console:

```
["120", "220"]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mj5G4/4/

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if the following works/not:

```
var data_list = jQuery("td:contains('"+seach_val+"')","table#data");
```

Notice the quotation `'` before the closing `"`. I remember I had a similar problem in the past, and I am looking to help you solve it as well :) hope that helps.

Comment: seemingly..I didnt try it though

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just loop through like this?

```
var searchString = "20";
var results = [];
$('td').each( function(index, element){
    if($(element).text().indexOf(searchString) != -1){
     results.push($(element).text());   
    }
});
alert(results);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XZWEh/1/